# Is there a way to open/read a database file created by linux command updatedb with C#?

Tags: c#, linux, solaris, locate

I'm just curious if anyone has done this before. I'd like to use the database file generated by updatedb on a linux or solaris machine and read from a c# app

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information.

Comment: So your talking linux + mono? Maybe update the tags to get the right audience.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379725/what-kind-of-database-do-updatedb-and-locate-use

Comment: I'm voting to close because in the end the question is "is there a library to read..." so I fear it's not a good question for SO. Correct me if I'm wrong.